# Hide an element with css on just a few pages

Tags: css

I'm looking for a quick and easy way to hide an element on just two pages that is otherwise in the sidebar on all pages.  I tried to do it with css but just can't seem to affect this one spot.  [This is one of the pages](http://emgraphics.net/ubt/personal/trusts/) and the client wants the FDIC logo in the sidebar gone. I tried adding page ID and the sidebar css to display:none, but can't work out the right combo. Am I on the right track?

```css
#page-id-63 .textwidget 
{display:none;}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't see any FDIC logo, the linked page just says 'Maintenance Mode'

Comment: woops, forgot I had that on.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to you know, remove the actual image.

Comment: I don't think this is a WP question since it is something I just want to hide with css. It looks like the advice on that page is what I already tried, too. I can't just hide the image, since it would still have the text below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#text-9 > .textwidget {
display: none;
}
```

Try this out, either include it in a tweaks stylesheet specifically for those couple pages or throw it between style tags in the head.

Edit: I see you have the page number defined as a class in the body tag, you can put this in your main stylesheet adjusting the first class for your specific page (ex. .page-id-13 instead of 63) ..

```css
.page-id-63 > #wrapper > #main > #secondary > #text-9 > .textwidget {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: this one did the trick perfectly! The others worked, but also hid other elements like the Facebook logo in the sidebar. Thanks so much

Comment: No problem, that's why you should use as specific a CSS selector as possible to avoid possible conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

"page-id-63" is a class, not an id on the page you linked, so you'd need:

```
.page-id-63 .textwidget {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are on the right track.  What you need to do is apply the style and then have a look at the element using your browser dev tools.  Then you will be able to see if

1. The style applied.
2. If any other styles are overriding it.

**Update**

Having checked your site now that is out of maintenance mode, try this

```
.page-id-63 .textwidget{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
.page-id-63 .widget-area .text-widget {
display:none;
}
```

as you have many text widgets, and only want to hide the one in the sidebar.